# Python cron job vs Kapacitor UDF

Tags: python, user-defined-functions, influxdb, kapacitor

I need to perform some background advanced calculations on my data after it is collected in InfluxDb which is stored on the edge server, which means I have limited resources for the calculations.
Also I cannot block the data collection while I do calculations.
I am weighing using Kapacitor UDF streams vs custom Python scripts.

Please note I need to make the scripts configurable so that I can easily deply them to different environments with different sensors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It probably makes little difference, in general, especially for 'simple' usecases, though I lean towards standalone python scripts. (It may be better to use Kapacitor if you can cover your usecase using the kapacitor language for this instead of python based UDFs, but I found it insufficient since I needed to retrieve additional data from other databases)

- Standalone python scripts could be a bit lighter, since you don't need to run the Kapacitor service.
- Standalone python scripts could be a bit more configurable. Kapacitor is also pretty configurable but you'd have to spend a bit of time learning how to use it.
- Standalone python scripts could be a bit more stable. I've experimented with python UDF's a couple of years ago and found them unstable and buggy. While this may have improved by now, you'd still be relying on this being supported and if `go` is not your language you might have trouble debugging and fixing issues yourself.